# ARM Assembly: Echoing characters from Read FIFO to Write FIFO in ARMv7 CPUlator. JTAG UART interface

Tags: arm, cpu

I am having trouble echoing characters that are not in parentheses from Read FIFO to Write FIFO. These characters are typed in the JTAG UART interface. The characters from Read FIFO are being read but are not being echoed.

---

```
.section .text
.global _start
 
.equ UART_BASE, 0xFF201000
.equ READ_FIFO_OFFSET, 0x00
.equ WRITE_FIFO_OFFSET, 0x04
.equ NUM_CHARS_TO_READ, 16   // Adjust based on your system
 
_start:
    // Infinite loop
    B loop
 
loop:
    // Read characters from the UART Read FIFO
    LDR R1, =UART_BASE
    LDR R2, =READ_FIFO_OFFSET
    LDR R3, =NUM_CHARS_TO_READ
read_loop:
    LDRB R0, [R1, R2]  // Read a character from the Read FIFO
    CMP R0, #0      // Check if the character is null (end of string)
    BEQ loop_end
 
    // Check if the character is a double quote (ASCII 0x22)
    CMP R0, #0x22
    BNE check_next_char
 
    // Start echoing characters until the next double quote
    B echo_chars
 
check_next_char:
    // Increment the offset for the next character in the loop
    ADD R2, R2, #1
    SUBS R3, R3, #1 // Decrement the character count
    BNE read_loop   // Continue reading if there are more characters
 
loop_end:
    // Retry reading from the UART (you might want to add a delay here)
    B loop
 
echo_chars:
    // Echo characters to the Write FIFO until the next double quote
    LDR R2, =WRITE_FIFO_OFFSET
echo_loop:
    STRB R0, [R1, R2]  // Echo the character to the Write FIFO
    ADD R2, R2, #1
    CMP R0, #0x22   // Check if the echoed character is a double quote
    BEQ loop        // If double quote, go back to reading
 
    // Increment to the next character in the loop
    ADD R2, R2, #1
    SUBS R3, R3, #1
    CMP R3, #0
    BNE read_loop   // Continue reading if there are more characters
 
    // If we reach here, we have echoed characters until the next double quote
    B loop
```

was not able to echo characters correctly

Comment: The `READ_FIFO` and `WRITE_FIFO` registers are at *fixed addresses* - you shouldn't be incrementing the addresses you're using (via `R2`), as then you're no longer addressing the right register.

Comment: is it jtag or is it uart, these are completely different things.